# El IF no me toma el valor determinado (8 y 16) No hay error sintáctico. PYTHON

Tags: python, condiciones, diccionarios

Estoy teniendo un error logico en la parte de la funcion que dice "def_asistencia_mat"

esta recibe valor de un diccionario. Van contando las clases, busco que al llegar a la 8 y la 16 se ejecute el codigo.

No logro encontrar el error ya que no percibe ninguno, debe ser un error logico.

Desde ya muchas gracias

- introducir el
  import datetime

  ```
  # AGREGAR CONTADOR PARA CADA MATERIA


  def agregar_clase_mat():

      fecha_actual = datetime.date.today()

      if fecha_actual in num_clase_mat:
          num_clase_mat[fecha_actual] += 1
      else:
          num_clase_mat[fecha_actual] = 1

      print(f"El numero de la clase es: {num_clase_mat [fecha_actual]} ")
      return num_clase_mat




  # FUNCIONES ASISTENCIAS


  ** def asistencia_mat():
      for x in range(20):
          agregar_clase_mat()

          asiste = input("CLASE MATEMATICA: Asistio hoy el alumno?  si/no: ")
          asistencias_mat = 0
          if asiste == "no":
              asistencias_mat += 0
          if asiste == "si":
              asistencias_mat += 1
              if num_clase_mat== 8:
  ```

  > aca esta el error

  ```
                  print("PRIMER EXAMEN HOY: ")
                  nota_1_mat = float(input("Ingrese nota alumno: "))

                  notas_mat.append(nota_1_mat)
                  if num_clase_mat == 16:
  ```

  > aca hay otro error

  ```
                   print("SEGUNDO EXAMEN HOY: ")
                   nota_2_mat = float(input("Ingrese nota alumno:")) **código aquí`
  ```

Comment: `if num_clase_mat== 8` no será `if x== 8` ??

Comment: No me funciono, pero muchas gracias igual!

Comment: Hola Bruno, tal vez en **def asistencia_mat():**  deberías usar **num_clase_mat = agregar_clase_mat()**, para instanciar **num_clase_mat** con la devolución de **asistencia_mat()**.

Answer (score 0):

El problema que tienes en tu codigo es que nunca va a entrar dentro de los condicionales

```
if num_clase_mat== 8: 
if num_clase_mat == 16:
```

num_clase_mat nunca sera un entero, si no que será, como bien dices en el enunciado: un diccionario

```
num_clase_mat = {}
num_clase_mat[fecha_actual] += 1
```

Por lo tanto, en cada iteracion el valor de num_clase_mat queda algo asi:

```
{datetime.date(2023, 3, 15): 1}
{datetime.date(2023, 3, 15): 2}
{datetime.date(2023, 3, 15): 3}
```

Es decir, nunca esto será igual a 8, ni a 16.

Lo que puedes hacer (por ejemplo, para mantener tu lógica) es que la funcion agregar_clase_mat, despues de agregar la info en el diccionario, retorne sólo el valor.

```
// en vez de 
return num_clase_mat
// pon
return num_clase_mat[fecha_actual]
```

Entonces el comparador del condicional lo comparas con este nuevo valor.

Otro fallo es el segundo condicional, lo tienes dentro del primer condicional, y deberia estas al mismo nivel.

Aquí te pongo la solución a tu problema:

```
import datetime

# Definir el diccionario num_clase_mat i arreglo notas_mat
num_clase_mat = {}
notas_mat = []

def agregar_clase_mat():

    fecha_actual = datetime.date.today()

    if fecha_actual in num_clase_mat:
        num_clase_mat[fecha_actual] += 1
    else:
        num_clase_mat[fecha_actual] = 1

    print(f"El numero de la clase es: {num_clase_mat [fecha_actual]} ")
    return num_clase_mat[fecha_actual]

def asistencia_mat():
    for x in range(20):
        lastClaseNum = agregar_clase_mat()
        asiste = input("CLASE MATEMATICA: Asistio hoy el alumno?  si/no: ")
        asistencias_mat = 0
        if asiste == "no":
            asistencias_mat += 0
        if asiste == "si":
            asistencias_mat += 1
            if lastClaseNum== 8: 
                print("PRIMER EXAMEN HOY: ")
                nota_1_mat = float(input("Ingrese nota alumno: "))

                notas_mat.append(nota_1_mat)
            if lastClaseNum == 16:
                print("SEGUNDO EXAMEN HOY: ")
                nota_2_mat = float(input("Ingrese nota alumno:"))
                    

asistencia_mat()
```

El problema de esta logica es que "mañana" la clase empezará por el 1 otra vez, y no seguira contando desde donde se ha quedado "hoy". Pero eso ya depende de lo que estés buscando hacer tienes que cambiar esta logica o no. Pero ten en cuetna esto, que al cambia de fecha (al dia siguiente) se empezará a contar las clases otra vez por el numero 1.